# Serializer.is_valid() raises Queryset error while serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) does not

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

The issue here is easy to fix and the reason I open it is that I don't understand what's happening.

Here's the code from django-rest-auth:

```
class PasswordResetView(GenericAPIView):

    """
    Calls Django Auth PasswordResetForm save method.

    Accepts the following POST parameters: email
    Returns the success/fail message.
    """

    serializer_class = PasswordResetSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create a serializer with request.data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        serializer.save()
        # Return the success message with OK HTTP status
        return Response(
            {"success": _("Password reset e-mail has been sent.")},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

It's the whole class and it surely works well.

I make a copy with a small change - instead of `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` I expand it:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    # Return the success message with OK HTTP status
    return Response(
        {"success": _("Password reset e-mail has been sent.")},
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK
    )
else:
    return Response(
        {"error": "Something's wrong."},
        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    )
```

When I run it I get

```
*AssertionError: 'PasswordResetView' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.*
```

The only difference is in using `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) (Ok) or just serializer.is_valid()` (fail).

Can somebody explain it to me? It's not the first time I see such an issue.

Of course I can write an empty `def get_quesryset(): return None` to fix it.
But the original code doesn't have get_queryset or get_object or anything and works fine.

Thanks!

Edit: here's my code, so that you can see it's really the same as original.

```
class PasswordResetView(GenericAPIView):

    """
    Calls Django Auth PasswordResetForm save method.

    Accepts the following POST parameters: email
    Returns the success/fail message.
    """

    serializer_class = PasswordResetSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create a serializer with request.data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            # Return the success message with OK HTTP status
            return Response(
                {"success": _("Password reset e-mail has been sent.")},
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
        else:
            return Response(
                {"error": "Something's wrong."},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

Comment: What versions of `django` and `django-rest-framework` are you using?

Comment: Is your view "GenericAPIView" or something else such as "viewsets.Modelviewset" ?

Comment: django 1.9.7, django-rest-framework 3.4.4

Comment: I use GenericAPIView same as original PasswordResetView. Basically I copied everything and changed post() only.